# How to fill angular 6 ngModel with some expression

Tags: angular

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuCYR.png)
Trying to populate discountPercentage based on original price and discounted price. discountPercentage is getting populated but not getting added to the model.

Note: As soon as I'm typing anything in discountPercentage input it started populating.

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="originalPrice" [(ngModel)]="ticket.originalPrice" name="originalPrice"/>

<input class="form-control" type="number" id="discountedPrice" [(ngModel)]="ticket.discountedPrice"name="discountedPrice" />

<input class="form-control" type="number" id="discountPercentage" [(ngModel)]="ticket.discountPercentage" name="discountPercentage" value="0" [value]="((ticket.originalPrice - ticket.discountedPrice)/ticket.originalPrice)*100" />
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I updated the question could you please have a look

Comment: Why are you using two values like this ```value="0" [value]="((ticket...."``` in discountPercentage??

Comment: I got the solution  and using `ngModelChange` to reflect the same

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your result into ticket.discountPercentage. Angular retrieves the value of ticket.discountPercentage Because of your model binding.

besides you have two value directive. if you want to use `[value]` directive you need to delete "value" directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngModelChange`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel), value change doesn't changes automatically.

```
(ngModelChange)="OnModelChangeTicket()"
```

and in your ts

```
  OnModelChangeTicket() {
    this.ticket.discountPercentage = ((this.ticket.originalPrice - this.ticket.discountedPrice) / this.ticket.originalPrice) * 100
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhotwh)

Comment: @Justcode, Sorry, I download by error, but I can not remove the download ::glups::

Comment: @eliseo what do you mean?